# Drop a table with primary key having foreign key reference to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to drop a table having primary key and referenced by foreign key on another table? I know, If I will try to write a simple `DROP` statement then **SSMS** will throw me an exception saying

```
Msg 3726, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Could not drop object 'dbo.Dept' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
```

May be the answer is simply **NO** but, I am looking for any work around as recently I was asked this in a Interview.

Comment: If you are interviewing for any sort of programming job you must recognized the importance of saying exactly what you mean.  You can practise that on StackOverflow.  See anything wrong with your subject line?  I do.

Answer (score 2):

You have to drop the CONSTRAINT on the (child) table.  That keeps the child table, but breaks the 'link' to the parent table.

Which is why I like to name my constraints. ("FK_EmployeeToDepartment" in this case).

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Employee]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
BEGIN DROP TABLE [dbo].[Employee] 
END 


IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Department]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
BEGIN DROP TABLE [dbo].[Department] 
END 


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Department](
    [DepartmentUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentName] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
    )


ALTER TABLE dbo.[Department] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Department PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([DepartmentUUID]) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_DepartmentName_Unique UNIQUE ([DepartmentName]) 
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ( 

    [EmployeeUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ParentDepartmentUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [SSN] [nvarchar](11) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [HireDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
    )

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Employee PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (EmployeeUUID) 
GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_SSN_Unique UNIQUE (SSN) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeToDepartment FOREIGN KEY (ParentDepartmentUUID) REFERENCES dbo.Department (DepartmentUUID) 
GO

/* this will fail here */
--DROP TABLE [dbo].[Department] 
GO

/* drop the constraint */
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeToDepartment 
GO

/* now it will work */
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Department] 
GO
```

Comment: And if/when I was interviewing someone and I asked the same question, and the person answered the question and at the end said "That is why I like to name my constraints", I'd be impressed.

Answer (score 1):

If you really intend to drop a table that's referenced by a foreign key constraint, then the foreign key constraint is no longer meaningful, right? Drop the foreign key constraint first, then drop the table.

```
create table foo (
  foo_id integer primary key
);

create table bar (
  bar_id integer not null,
  foo_id integer not null,
  constraint bar_foo_id_fkey 
    foreign key (foo_id)
    references foo (foo_id),
  primary key (bar_id, foo_id)
);

drop table foo;  -- Results in an error because of the foreign key constraint.

alter table bar
drop constraint bar_foo_id_fkey;

drop table foo;  -- Drops table "foo".
```

You might still have work to do regarding existence of the column "bar"."foo_id", and regarding the primary key in "bar".

Answer (score 0):

Drop the referenced table first and then parent table. That's why while creating reference you should choose `ON DELETE CASCADE` and/or `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

It's purposefully throwing that error and stopping you from committing the mistake of making referenced table Orphan/Zombie.

Comment: These "cascades" have to do with deleting rows, not with dropping tables.